# Inserting into a table with a character limit

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to insert into a table, but keep on getting a character limit error. When I try to limit the characters in my secondary table using the LEFT function under SELECT, I get another error. Is there a way for me to limit the number of characters? Here is the outline:

```
insert into PrimaryTable
select
    D.Year,
    LEFT(D.Product_ID,5),
    LEFT(SUM(D.SALES),5) as SALES,
    LEFT(SUM(D.UNITS),5) as UNITS
from DataTable D
where UNITS <> 0
group by 1,2;
```

EDIT: Changed D.SUM(SALES) to SUM(D.SALES), still receiving the error.

Comment: Could you share the error you're getting?

Comment: the error is "found a keyword and expecting an identifier"

Comment: Should be `SUM(D.SALES)` not `D.SUM(SALES)`

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it and I'm still getting the error

Comment: Can you do a `show create table PrimaryTable;`

Comment: I get an error saying "Found table (at char 13) expecting a keyword"

Answer (score 0):

The result of the `SUM` would be a number. However, the input of the `LEFT` function must be a string. Therefore, you should convert the result into the string like the following:

```
insert into PrimaryTable
select
D.Year,
LEFT(CONVERT(D.Product_ID,char),5),
LEFT(CONVERT(SUM(D.SALES),char),5) as SALES,
LEFT(CONVERT(SUM(D.UNITS),char),5) as UNITS
from DataTable D
where UNITS <> 0
group by 1,2;
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but I'm getting the error "found "LEFT" (at char 169) expecting an identifier found a keyword"

Comment: @Lonewolf That kind of error makes me suspect you forgot a comma somewhere. And btw, it's safer to specify the columns you insert into.

Comment: @LukStorms I double checked my commas and it looks fine. In fact, I'm able to insert everything except for one column, which gives me the error above. Could you tell me how to specify the columns? Maybe that might resolve it

Comment: @Lonewolf just put the list of column names after the table name: `insert into mytable (col1, col2) select ...`. [Here's a tutorial page](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp). The benefit is that even if your table gets extra fields, the insert will still work.